# using .htaccess to 410 any wildcard url that contains a question mark

Tags: .htaccess

I have looked and searched and have not quite found the answer to this question - I think it should be pretty simple but I am not sure.

Basically, I would love to learn how to use .htaccss to 410 (Gone) **any URL on my site that contains a question mark.**

For example

A URL like this I'd want to have a 410

mysite.com/content/page.htm?no_redirect=true

but leave alone the original url
mysite.com/content/page.htm

When I created the mobile version of my site in May, a coding issue created a lot of pages with a wildard/question mark, and I'd like to tell google those are gone with .htaccess.

Thanks for any assistance - great site and resource here!

Comment: You are not interested in processing or redirecting the URLs with query strings, correct? You just want to provide a 410 flat out? And further, you really want to apply this to any and all URLs submitted with a query string? There are no exceptions?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - yes, that is correct.  I do not use query strings in any URL on my site - so any URL that has one should not be indexed, and should be 410.   I don't need it to redirect.  Thank you for your reply.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all URLs including a `?`, you are actually asking for any URL with a non-empty query string, matched with Apache's `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. You may use a `RewriteCond` to match any character with a `.` to indicate it is nonempty, then use `RewriteRule` to send the 410 code.

You may want to couple this with [an `ErrorDocument` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html) to serve an error page accompanying the 410 code.

```
# Make sure an error page is defined for 410
ErrorDocument 410 /path/to/custom/410.html

# For any non-empty query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.
# Match any path and send a 410 response
# The [L] prevents further matches from being executed
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]
```

#### Addendum after comments:

To apply the 410 only to URLs containing the `no_redirect=true` parameter, you may use that as the expression in `RewriteCond`. Since `%{QUERY_STRING}` contains the entire query string (except the `?`) it will work to just use the entire `key=value` pair.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} no_redirect=true [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]
```

Note I also added `[NC]` (no-case) to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Michael, you are fast!  I am going to play with this first thing tomorrow to see if I can get it to work and test etc.  I will let you know.  Your time is so appreciated - not every day in this world you can get a complete stranger to help - for that, thank you!

Comment: I was thinking about this, and wanted to ask:  Is it possible, using .htaccess, to 410 (Gone) any url that contains a common, specific word or characters, instead of just doing it if it has a non-empty query string like above?  The URL's that I want gone all contain a ?, but the also have in common this:    no_redirect=true        So, any URL that has no_redirect=true in it - is there a way to 410 it using .htaccess?  An example of a URL that has this commonality is:  mysite.com/content/page.htm?no_redirect=true

Comment: @DKB Certainly. The `RewriteCond` I have above is very generic - it uses only `.` to match _any single character_. To require `no_redirect=true`, you may use that in the condition instead: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} no_redirect=true`

Comment: Michael, that worked perfectly.   I know it was pretty simple to you, but for someone like me who is not totally comfortable with htaccess yet, it was incredibly helpful.   I went with that option instead of just 410-ing the non-empty query string, since, I remembered that I have a search function on my site's blog section that would have that, so the 2nd solution was perfect.